# WP custom post type query does not return custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following CPT:

```
        array(
            'slug'        => 'articles',
            'single_name' => 'Article',
            'plural_name' => 'Articles',
            'menu_name'   => 'Articles',
            'description' => '',
            'dashicon'    => 'dashicons-media-default'
        ),
```

and the following custom taxonomy which shows up under the articles CPT:

```
        array(
            'slug'        => 'author',
            'single_name' => 'Author',
            'plural_name' => 'Authors',
            'menu_name'   => '→ Authors',
            // This is where you sync the taxonomy to the post types above
            'post_type'   => ['articles', 'news']
        ),
```

Now, I am trying to create a single-articles.php in which I query a single article, to include all custom taxonomy information.

I've tried all variations of:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'articles',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field' => 'slug'
        ),
    ),
);
```

I am relatively new to PHP & WP and am not 100% sure how to retrieve the data. In Javascript you would get an object back through which one can traverse. When adding `print_r($my_query)` I don't get what back what I am looking for. Earlier in the document I already initiated the loop:

```
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post()
```

but I can't figure out why php/wp doesn't show all data included in the object. Ideally, **I want to query only the single article and get all data back, to include info about all attached taxonomies**. I **do not** want to query articles BY the taxonomy So I have two questions:

1) How do I query this correctly to get results back?
2) How do I display this data on the frontend?

Edit: [According to this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) `tax_query` is ignored when `is_singular()` is true. `print_r( is_singular() )` results in `1` (aka true?!), would this make a difference?

I also have custom post types attached to the taxonomies. I need to retrieve this info as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your taxonomy slug is `author` NOT `authors`

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'articles',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'author',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'your-term-here',
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can Use single-{posttype}.php for the single template.

And, if you have register your post type with the has_archive argument set to true, then you can use archive-{posttype}.php for your archive template.

You can check [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: Sry, I edited the post to correct the issue. Can you tell me how I would retrieve the info on the frontend, given that this query would work?

Comment: Check my recent edit ... you need to pass `'terms' => 'your-term',`  to get all articles from specific term